# How to display json in browser or console?

Tags: c#

I want to know that how can i possible to display json values in a browser or console? Is there is any changes required in my present code?

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public static DataTable GetAlltheatredet()
{
    try
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;database=Mytable;uid=root;";
        string query = "SELECT Tnme FROM `Mytable`.`tdetails`";
        MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        ma.Fill(DS);
        return DS.Tables[0];  
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

My Function

```
[HttpGet]
public void jsonvalues()
{
    List<string> List = new List<string>();
    RootObject ro = new RootObject();
    DataTable dtaltheat = GetAlltheatredet();
    foreach (DataRow drow in dtaltheat.Rows)
    {
        string theatnme = drow["TheatreName"].ToString();
        ro.name = theatnme;
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
        if(jsonString != null)
        { 
            List.Add(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using datatable to fetch my table data and create a root object and add each value to object and convert the object to json.

Comment: You aren't returning anything... `void`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `return` response from server, to receive at client side.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage jsonvalues()
{
    //your code

    //send response with status code 200 (OK)
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, List );
}
```

Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849034/Csharp-Web-API-HTTP-GET-with-a-Request-Body